# First name missing, can i still fly?

Tags: air-travel

In my legal documents, in my passport too my full name is mentioned but while booking the flight ticket i didn't mentioned my full name, just mentioned my first name and the last name because my first name is my surname too. so would that be a problem while boarding in domestic flight?

Comment: Domestic in which country?

Comment: Not worth an answer, but for American airlines transatlantic flight, i'm still "eri" , instead of "eric", as long as eveyrthing else is fine...

Comment: How do you mean "my first name is my surname too"? That is unclear at least to me.

Comment: @mts same first and last name, think Henry Henry

Comment: @ElliottTangoFoxtrot. For real examples, try Jerome K. Jerome and Ford Madox Ford.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience is the following

- I have three middle names and never use them on any airplane ticket.
- Many airlines state in their terms & conditions that they require your names for the ticket as it appears on your government official ID (in my case it's with the 3 middle names)
- I never use my middle name though, and never had an issue. Worth mentioning is the following: on the first part of an e-ticket or your boarding pass, you will usually see only your first and last name, and sometimes not even this.

Also, simple spelling errors in the name don´t matter to anyone in most of the cases.

So, I would say it's not an issue at all, and I´ve travelled in North America, Africa, Asia and Oceania without any problems.